# Prevent direct access to the back-end Ms Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have this problem, I can create a setup for my app/database but everyone can open the backend file which is an MS Access database. I want it so we can only access the database using the frontend app. Please help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a separate front end app that accesses the database, and keep the database file somewhere secure where direct access to it is limited/restricted. You should also password-protect the file in case someone does manage to get it See tip #10 here: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/10things/?p=552 for info about password protection (though you might find the other tips useful as well).

Comment: The password protection in the cited article is for the SCREEN SAVER, not for the database. Of course, Access database passwords are just a form of "security theater" and not real security, so my point is kind of moot.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, don't rely on Access password protection.  It can be cracked in minutes by tools freely available on the internet.

I would get Garry Robinson's book [Real World Microsoft Access Database Protection and Security](http://www.vb123.com/map/)

It is the most comprehensive guide to securing an Access database that there is.

A first step, however, would be to put the backend file in a restricted folder.

Comment: Are you certain that the new encryption available in ACCDB is so easily cracked? I certainly agree that database passwords are useless, but I think you're actually out of date in regard to the issue of crackability.

Comment: You may well be right.  To be honest, our primary focus moved to ASP.NET after Access 2003.  So although we maintain a system on Access 2007, I haven't really worked with it.  However, I still mistrust files.

Comment: I agree with your mistrust of encryption to protect a file that the users have to have access to through the file system in order to use. That's yet another reason why I consider the whole database password thing "security theater".